# avdmanager: create avd with skin

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I create my avd's with the command line.  Previously, it was `android create avd`. Now, I need to use `avdmanager create avd`.

I have no problem with this, but apparently the `--skin` option has been removed.

When creating a new avd via the command line, how is the skin to be used specified?

Comment: That's not possible through command line. see this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-comparison . Skin has no command line option

Answer (score 1):

Use `-d` or `--device` option

You can see all the skin options via `avdmanager list device`

And you can see all other `create avd` options via `avdmanager --help create avd`